# Are HTML files edited with Word cross-browser compatible?

Tags: html, cross-browser, microsoft, text-editor

I edit a simple Word file (no images etc.) and want to put it on my website so that it is accessible to all visitors. So far, I exported it to PDF and it worked fine. But in order to save the hassle of exporting to PDF each time, I am thinking of saving the file in "Filtered HTML" format, which can be directly edited with Word. My question is: is such an HTML file readable by all current browsers on all computers?

Comment: What version of Microsoft Word are you using?

Comment: Watch out when producing HTML in MS Word.  It produces truly awful code.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have Office 365 on Windows 10.

Comment: @Steve I know.. I do not intend to edit this HTML in any other program except Word. It is just a replacement to PDF.

Comment: You should try it and tell us.

Comment: This is something I would not even consider. HTML and basic CSS is easy to learn and will produce much more streamline files which will be easily edited in Notepad or Brackets and will be better for website performance etc.